Issue Installing ThermalSeparation Library in OMEdit
I am experiencing an issue while trying to install the ThermalSeparation library in OMEdit. Despite the library being listed in the 'index.json' file, indicating its availability, it does not appear in the 'install libraries' box within OMEdit. I have attempted to update the software, but the problem persists
I tried to modify the link of a library that is appearing in OMEdit but I didn't get any results. I would like to know how I can make the ThermalSeparation library appear in the "install library" box.

You need to select experimental to see all the unsupported libraries when you go to install libraries.
